# combining numpy arrays and masking

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

i have the following problem. In know that with numpy i can read datafiles with genfromtext. I can then select the records from that with a mask(from the dictionary).

```
>>> gln = a[a['AA2'] == 'GLN']
>>> gln['mean'].mean()
62.805000305175781
```

How can i do this with a combination of arrays instead of reading those from disk?

```
x=[]
y=[]
ov=[]
aa=[]

a = numpy.array(x,y,ov,aa)         <== does not actually work
gln = a[a[3] == 'GLN']
gln['mean'].mean()
```

How do i get this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep in mind that in Python, the object produced by `[]` is generally referred to as a `list`, not an `array`. So with that in mind, I'm assuming that your real question is "How do I convert 4 independent python `list`s into a 2-dimensional `numpy` array?"

The answer depends on how you want the `list`s to be laid out in the array. Assuming each list represents a row, you could do this:

```
>>> x = range(0, 4)
>>> y = range(4, 8)
>>> ov = range(8, 12)
>>> aa = range(12, 16)
>>> numpy.array([x, y, ov, aa])
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14, 15]])
```

Or, if each list represents a column, you could do this:

```
>>> numpy.array(zip(x, y, ov, aa))
array([[ 0,  4,  8, 12],
       [ 1,  5,  9, 13],
       [ 2,  6, 10, 14],
       [ 3,  7, 11, 15]])
```

Then, you can use boolean indexing just as you did with the `array` produced by `genfromtxt`:

```
>>> a = numpy.array(zip(x, y, ov, aa))
>>> a[a == 1]
array([ 1,  5,  9, 13,  3,  7, 11, 15])
```

It may be that you're looking for some other way of combining `x`, `y`, `ov`, and `aa` into an array. You're going to have to specify what's in the lists and the shape of the desired output in that case.

Comment: i am getting a type error here. TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'numpy.ndarray' and 'int'

Comment: @tarrasch, I don't have that problem. What version of numpy are you using? What's the value of `numpy.version.version`? But the `%` is irrelevant -- that was just a quick way of producing a boolean array.

Comment: never mind. it seems i am stupid. could you change your example to a[a==1] ? The % sign messes up at my system and makes the example not working. thank you for pointing it out. accepted.